# Validation in php for dropdown menu

Tags: php, html

I have a html form which has 20 dropdown field generated by the function as below....

```
<?php
      $sub_1 = subject_show (subject_1, $scl_unique_id, $cls_sec_bat);
      if ($sub_1)
      {?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sub_1;?></td>
        <td><select name="subject_1" id="subject_1" style="min-width:100px">
          <?php 
          if(isset($subject_1)){?>
          <option value="<?php echo $subject_1; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $subject_1; ?></option>
          <?php }else{ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $sub_1;?>" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"><?php echo $sub_1;?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          <option value="<?php echo MAR_ABS;?>"><?php echo MAR_ABS;?></option>
          <option value="<?php echo MAR_NA;?>"><?php echo MAR_NA;?></option>
          <?php
          for ($i=0; $i<=100; $i++)
          {
            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
          }
          ?>
          </select></td>
      </tr>
     <?php
      }
      ?>
```

In the code, if the function has the value on $sub_1 then the drop down field printed on html output with a name subject_1. If not it will not printed.

The same code I have 20 times. If the function has value in $sub_2 or $sub_3 or $sub_4 till $sub_20 the field printed with a name as subject_2 or subject_3 or subject_4 till subject_20.

Any dropdown field can be printed depending on the userinput and function output.

When the reading time, I am reading all the 20 names like

```
if (isset($_POST['save_exit']))
    {
        $roll_number = strtoupper(trim(implode(' ', preg_split('/\s+/', $_POST["roll_number"]))));
        $subject_1 = $_POST["subject_1"];
        $subject_2 = $_POST["subject_2"];
        $subject_3 = $_POST["subject_3"];
        $subject_4 = $_POST["subject_4"];
        $subject_5 = $_POST["subject_5"];
        $subject_6 = $_POST["subject_6"];
        $subject_7 = $_POST["subject_7"];
        $subject_8 = $_POST["subject_8"];
        $subject_9 = $_POST["subject_9"];
        $subject_10 = $_POST["subject_10"];
        $subject_11 = $_POST["subject_11"];
        $subject_12 = $_POST["subject_12"];
        $subject_13 = $_POST["subject_13"];
        $subject_14 = $_POST["subject_14"];
        $subject_15 = $_POST["subject_15"];
        $subject_16 = $_POST["subject_16"];
        $subject_17 = $_POST["subject_17"];
        $subject_18 = $_POST["subject_18"];
        $subject_19 = $_POST["subject_19"];
        $subject_20 = $_POST["subject_20"];
```

I dont want user to submit empty dropdown list so I am wrinting validation as

```
if(empty(subject_1))
{
say error
}

if(empty(subject_2))
{
say error
}
```

I am wrting this 20 times for all subject.

The problem is when the user has only three subject with a name like subject_1 and subject_2 and subject_3 in the forum. It will give the error for all the remaining 17 subjects.

How can I read validate only the subjects available on the form??

Please let me know if its not clear.

Comment: Please post an example of what the HTML form looks like after PHP renders it (from the page source).  This is crying out for a refactoring using PHP's `[]` array syntax in the form element `name=` attributes.

Comment: I have posted the form code right. Please let me know what u want ?? how can i get it..

Comment: You need to check to see if the form element was posted but the value is blank - `isset($_POST["subject_#"])` / `$subject_1 == ''`. So your `if` could be - `if(isset($_POST["subject_1"] && empty($subject_1)){ error message}`

Comment: do you really want all the `$subject_` variables?

Comment: Hi sean I did like you before but its not workin...Yes bansi I need 20 subjects so 20 varaibles.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in less code like the following

```
for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
    $var = "subject_$i";
    if (isset($$var) && empty($$var)){echo "error";}
}
```

If you don't need all those `$subject_` variables you can directly validate `$_POST`

```
for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
    if (isset($_POST["subject_$i"]) && empty($_POST["subject_$i"])){echo "error";}
}
```

Comment: this will again give for 20 values.. i want to validate only the value posted from the form

Comment: Yes Directly also I validate but no result

Comment: you mean you need to find only values which are blank? like subject_1 is posted but blank ->report, subject_2 is not posted from form so ignore?

Comment: check the edit i have made, you may require this. this will check if the post is empty and ignore variables if not posted. (check the `isset()` added)

Comment: sorry to say but its the same

Answer (score 0):

Try posting the subjects as an array to your form handler.

Then, you can check easily:

```
if (count($subject) < $_POST['numberNeeded']) {
   // say error
}
```

In `$subject[0]` you'd find the first subject, `$subject[1]` would contain the second, etc.

In your form:

```
<select name="subject[]" id="subject_1" style="min-width:100px">
<!-- Do everything you need -->
</select>
<select name="subject[]" id="subject_2" ...
```

Below, add the following field (calculated using php). In this example, let's assume you'd need 5 subjects.

```
<input type="hidden" name="numberNeeded" value="5" />
```

As an added remark: you might also want to consider JavaScript validation as a plus...